# Affecting all data in Database While Using Modal

Tags: php, jquery

Without Modal, *user_timeout.php* does not have a problem but When I use modal, as you can see at the picture below the problem is. But they have same logic codes so I dont know what the problem is. I want to use modal for some quality design so help me guys thank you

**logs.php**

```
 <a  rel="tooltip"  title="Timeout" id="<?php echo $idlogs; ?>" href="user_timeout.php<?php echo '?id='.$idlogs; ?>" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-minus icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Manual Time-Out</a>
```

And for Modal

```
 <a rel="tooltip"  title="timeout" id="<?php echo $idlogs; ?>" href="#timeout<?php echo $idlogs; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-pencil icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Manual Time-Out</a>
 <?php include('modal_time_user.php'); ?>
```

**user_timeout.php**

```
 <?php $get_id= $_GET['id']; ?>
       <div class="container">
      <div class="margin-top">
        <div class="row">   
        <div class="span12">    
        <?php 
        $query=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select * from user_logs_tbl where id ='$get_id'")or die(mysqli_error());
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
         $iduser=$row['user_id'];
         $idlogs=$row['id'];
        ?>
         <div class="alert alert-info"><i class="icon-pencil></i>&nbsp;Manual Time-out</div>
        <p><a class="btn btn-info" href="logs.php"><i class="icon-arrow-left icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Back</a></p>
   <div class="addstudent">
   <div class="details">Please Enter Details Below</div>    
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


  <div class="control-group">

        <br>    
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="margin-left:10%;" for="inputEmail">Time-Out:</label>        
                <div class="controls">
                <input type="time" id="inputEmail" name="timeout" placeholder="Time">
                </div>
            </div>
<br>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
        <button name="timeouts" type="submit" style="margin-left:16%;" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>             

        </div>      
        </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['timeouts'])){

    $timeout=$_POST['timeout'];
    $timeout = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', 
    $timeout)));            
    mysqli_query($dbcon,"UPDATE user_logs_tbl set time_out = '$timeout' where id='$idlogs'")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));

       $yourURL="logs.php"; 
echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
      }
     ?>
```

But If I change it into modal form, it's working but all data will change if I change one
**modal_time_user.php**

```
   <div id="timeout<?php echo $idlogs; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Time</strong></div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
   <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Time-Out :</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="time" id="inputEmail" name="time_out" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}"  required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <button name="enter" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Close</button>
</div>
</div>

  <?php




if (isset($_POST['enter'])){

$timeout=$_POST['time_out'];
$timeout = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $timeout))); 
mysqli_query($dbcon,"UPDATE user_logs_tbl SET time_out='$timeout' where id = '$idlogs'")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));

$yourURL="logs.php";
echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
}
?>
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbXTM.png)

[After Inserting a Time Out In USER ID 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Nvw.png)

Comment: The Reason is that your `$idlogs` is empty.... print and check your query...

Comment: @Nawin how did it empty? I already print it out check this https://imgur.com/a/BLot9, I echo inside of the modal

Comment: Show your update query in `modal_time_user.php` file

Comment: @Nawin how can i show it into you?